# Powershell function-get multple values

Tags: powershell

I have file 1.csv

```
number, name # column name
1,john
2,mike
3,test
4,test2
...
```

I created function for returning all values from this csv (number,name)

```
Function Get-CSV {

 [CmdletBinding()]

    param (
    # CSV File path
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$path
    )

    #Create an hashtable variable
    [hashtable]$return = @{}

    Import-Csv $path |  
         ForEach-Object { 

         $number = $_.number 
         $name = $_.name
         $return.name = $name
         $return.number = $number
         return $return 

     }

      # return $return un-commenting this line don't change output 

}

# calling function

$a = Get-CSV "C:\Users\1.csv"

$a.number
$a.name
```

I get only one (last row from CSV) - `a.name = test2 and a.number = 4`

How to get all rows from CSV when calling this function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to construct an array of hashtables for this to work. Even better, I would create an array of objects because it gives you control over the property names. You can change the function definition to:

```
Function Get-CSV {
[CmdletBinding()]

    param (
    # CSV File path
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$path
    )

    #Create an empty array variable
    $return = @()

    Import-Csv $path |  
        ForEach-Object { 
            $return += ,(New-Object PSObject -property @{'name'= $_.name; 'number'= $_.number})
        }

    return $return
}
```

This gives you:

```
$a = Get-CSV "C:\Users\1.csv"
$a 

name  number
----  ------
john  1
mike  2
test  3
test2 4
```

**Note**

I'm not sure on your exact use case, but `Import-Csv` already gives you the information back as an object, so there may not be a need to create a separate one.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of googling and try/errors found solution:

Function Get-CSV {

```
 [CmdletBinding()]

    param (
    # CSV File path
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$path
    )

       Import-Csv $path |  
         ForEach-Object { 


         $number = $_.number 
         $name = $_.name
         [pscustomobject]@{

         name = $name
         number = $number
          }

     }


}
```